# Send Attachments using PubNub SDK

Tags: android, pubnub

currently I am working on a chat application using PubNub SDK. I have visited through PubNub [Publish/Subscribe](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe) guide , As I am getting It has functionality to send text messages ,but I didn't find a way to send attachments (Images /Audio /Videos ). I have searched over blogs (stackoverflow,github) but didn't find the answer . I am confused whether PubNub supports attachments or not . Can anybody help me to find out the real solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New PubNub Feature Update

PubNub now support File Upload as a native feature in its SDKs. [See JavaScript SDK Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-files) for more details. Change the SDK selection to choose your preferred language. If the feature isn't yet supported in a particular SDK, just let PN support know you need it.

File Upload is also implemented in the [PubNub Chat Framework](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/reference/files).

---

*The following is still valid but no longer necessary.*

**PubNub File Sharing Best Practice/Options**

PubNub supports non-binary data up to 32KB per published message. If you were sending attachments, you would likely just upload the file to a hosted file system like Amazon S3, Google Drive or the like and then publish the resulting URL to the hosted file via PubNub.

[There is a way to break the file up in to multiple chunks (< 32KB) and reassemble to on the subscriber end](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/45/transfer-files-and-large-messages-with-pubnub-with-no-backend-requirement) but this is not the optimal way to share files. The above is best practice.